# Отсортировать массив структур. Си

Tags: c, массивы, сортировка, структуры

Есть структура

```
struct internet_prov {
    char name[20];
    unsigned int speed;
    float tariff;
};
```

Нужно написать функцию которая выполняет действие над массивом (размер 10) указателей на структуры этого типа. Функция должна вывести К(задается пользователем) структур с самым дорогим тарифом. То есть для начала нужно отсортировать этот массив по полю *tariff*. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Comment: воспользуйтесь стандартной функцией `qsort` и переопределите в ней компаратор.

Comment: Вы попробовали написатэ код функции самостоятельно? В чём возникли затруднения?

Comment: @pavel я так и планировал сделать, но не знаю как указать что нужно сортировать по полю tariff

Comment: @0xdb да, в том как сортировать массив именно по нужному полю структуры

Comment: @Паша Компоратор написать. Вам уже один ответ предложен. Попробуйте и опубликуйте результат.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете использовать стандартную C функцию `qsort`, объявленную в заголовке `<stdlib.h>`.

Ниже приведена демонстрационная программа, которая показывает, как можно отсортировать массив указателей на структуру.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int cmp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const struct internet_prov *left  = *(const struct internet_prov **)a;
    const struct internet_prov *right = *(const struct internet_prov **)b;

    return (right->tariff < left->tariff) - (left->tariff < right->tariff);
}

#define N 3

int main( void )
{
    struct internet_prov * prov[N];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        char name[] = "A";
        name[0] += i;
        prov[i] = (internet_prov *)malloc(sizeof(internet_prov));

        strcpy(prov[i]->name, name);
        prov[i]->speed = rand() % 100;
        prov[i]->tariff = rand() % 100 / 10.0f;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("%s %u %f\n", prov[i]->name, prov[i]->speed, prov[i]->tariff);
    }

    printf("\n");

    qsort(prov, N, sizeof(struct internet_prov *), cmp);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("%s %u %f\n", prov[i]->name, prov[i]->speed, prov[i]->tariff);
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        free(prov[i]);
    }
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль может выглядеть следующим образом

```
A 41 6.700000
B 34 0.000000
C 69 2.400000

B 34 0.000000
C 69 2.400000
A 41 6.700000
```

Comment: Интересный `return`. А почему не как обычно `(l < r ? -1 : l == r ? 0 : 1)`?

Comment: @avp  В программировании одну и ту же проблему можно решить разными способами.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow а как будет выглядеть функция _cmp_, если я буду работать с массивом структур и сортировать в порядке убывания?

Comment: @Паша Тело функции будет выглядеть как     const struct internet_prov left  = *(const struct internet_prov *)a;
    const struct internet_prov right = *(const struct internet_prov *)b;

    return (left->tariff < right->tariff) - (right->tariff < left->tariff);

Comment: @Паша Я неправильно написал. Будет return (left.tariff < right.tariff) - (right.tariff < left.tariff); То есть обращение к членам объекта через точку, так как это уже не указатель.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow ну да, естественно через точку. Спасибо огромное, все работает!

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `qsort` с соответствующей функцией сравнения, примерно

```
int comp(const void * p1, const void * p2)
{
    struct internet_prov * i1 = (struct internet_prov*)p1;
    struct internet_prov * i2 = (struct internet_prov*)p2;
    // Сортируем по тарифу
    if (i1->tariff > i2->tariff) return 1;
    if (i1->tariff < i2->tariff) return -1;
    // Потом сортируем по скорости
    if (i1->speed > i2->speed) return 1;
    if (i1->speed < i2->speed) return -1;
    // и по названию
    return strcmp(i1->name,i2->name);
}
```

Comment: `i1->speed > i2->tariff` что-то не то)

Comment: @pavel  copy-paste подводит :(